"Apt" Upgrade behavior ubuntu 22.04
Maybe a dumb question.
I have two ubuntu server running the same services, the same operation system version, the same hardware, equal configuration - equal, because one as primary, the second as secondary server (DDNS, DHCP, etc.). That's the only difference.
For example:
I see 10 packages can be upgraded, i do it on the first (primary server). Then i go to my secondary server to do the same... where are not 10 packages to be upgraded, they are kept back. Maybe one or two days later, i can upgrade the package on the secondary server too - no longer kept back.

Please take a look at this question.

True, this article describe why packages are kept back by apt. But in my case, i can update just one of two identically server ... that's strange. Yesterday i could update the first machine, today im able to give the second machine the same update.

There is nothing strange in your apt upgrade behaviour. That the machines get the updates at a different time is caused by phased updates.
Take a look at this article which describes a bit more detailed how phased updates are managed:

Phased updates depend on a value derived from your machine’s “Machine ID”, as well as the package name and package version. The neat thing about this is that phasing is determined completely at the client end; no identifiable information (or indeed any new information at all) is ever sent to the server to achieve update phasing.

You think your machines are identical, but they are not. They may use the same OS, are configured the same way, but they have a different machine id.
